Single-spa-vue micro frontends mounting in wrong container
I am currently attempting to add a micro-frontend to our single-spa app.  There is a mix of vue2 and vue3 apps.  In this particular case the 2 micro-frontends being loaded in the parent app are both vue3.
Problem: There are 2 apps (running on ports 9021 and 4041), an app that is the page header, the second app is the content. When the apps are ran, they both compile without errors. They also run fine and mount fine in isolation (meaning i can run them each individually in single-spa).  The issue arises when they both run, the second app, or maybe the second one to load, mounts to BOTH target containers.  Essentially both the apps are a duplicate of one another, either the header or the content app.
My setup:
Layout in index.html parent app. (there are other inactive routes not included here)
<template id="single-spa-layout">
    <single-spa-router>
        <main
                class="v-application v-application--is-ltr theme--light"
                data-app="true"
        >
            <div class="v-application--wrap">
                <application name="@ft/header-v3"></application>

                <div class="main-app">
                    <route default>
                        <application loader="mountLoader" name="@ft/content-v3"></application>
                    </route>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>

    </single-spa-router>
</template>


My remotes in parent app
let remotes: { [name: string]: RemoteModule } = {
    "@ft/header-v3": {
        importName: "header_v3/app",
        path: `header_v3@${process.env.HEADER_V3_URL}`,
    },
    "@ft/content-v3": {
        importName: "content/app",
        path: `content@${process.env.CONTENT_URL}`,
    },
}

The bootstrap logic for registering the apps in parent app

async function addModuleScript(moduleUrl) {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        const element = document.createElement("script");
        element.src = moduleUrl;
        element.type = "text/javascript";
        element.async = true;
        element.onload = () => {
            element.parentElement?.removeChild(element);
            resolve();
        };
        element.onerror = (err: Event | string) => {
            element.parentElement?.removeChild(element);
            reject(err);
        };
        document.head.appendChild(element);
    });
}
async function dynamicImport(appName: string): Promise<Application> {
    let remote = remotes[appName];
    if (remote.path.split("@").length !== 2) {
        throw new Error(`URL mis-configured for remote '${appName}'`);
    }
    const [moduleName, moduleUrl] = remote.path.split("@");
    await __webpack_init_sharing__("default");
    await addModuleScript(moduleUrl);
    const container = window[moduleName];
    // @ts-ignore
    await container.init(__webpack_share_scopes__.default);
    const component = `.${remote.importName.replace(moduleName, "")}`;
    const factory = await container.get(component);
    return factory();
}

const data = {
    loaders: {
        mountLoader: `<div class="ft-loading"><div id="loading"></div></div>`,
    },
};

// @ts-ignore
const routes = constructRoutes(rootLayout, data);
let applications = constructApplications({
    routes,
    loadApp: ({ name }) => dynamicImport(name),
});
constructLayoutEngine({ routes, applications });

for (let cfg of applications) {
    registerApplication({
        name: cfg.name,
        activeWhen: cfg.activeWhen,
        app: cfg.app,
        customProps: {
            parentSession: inMemSession,
        },
    });
}

My webpack config in parent app
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
    let path = "/";
    if (argv.mode === "production") {
        path = "/parent/";
    }
    return {
        mode: "development",
        entry: "./src/index",
        devtool: "source-map",
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            },
            allowedHosts: "all",
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: path,
            filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                inject: true,
                template: "./public/index.html",
                favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
            }),

            new ModuleFederationPlugin({
                name: "parent",
                filename: "remoteEntry.js",
                remotes: {},
                shared: require("./package.json").dependencies,
            }),
            new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(require("dotenv-flow").config().parsed),
        ],
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
                    options: {
                        presets: [require.resolve("@babel/preset-typescript")],
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [".jsx", ".js", ".json", ".ts", ".tsx"],
            fallback: {
                process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
                fs: false,
                os: false,
                path: false,
            },
        },
    };
};


My header main.ts that sets up single-spa
const vueLifecycles = singleSpaVue({
    createApp,
    appOptions: {
        render() {
            return h(App, {
                name: this.name,
            });
        },
    },
    handleInstance: async (app, props: SpaProps) => {
        const bs: BootstrapResult = await appBootstrap(true, props.parentSession);

        app.use(MdbPlugin);
        app.use(bs.rbac).use(bs.ff).use(bs.pinia);
    },
});

export const bootstrap = vueLifecycles.bootstrap;
export const mount = vueLifecycles.mount;
export const unmount = vueLifecycles.unmount;

The header vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = webpack.container;
const { dependencies: deps, name } = require("./package.json");
require("dotenv-flow").config();

const webpackOptions = {
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    output: {
        filename:
            process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
                ? "[name].[fullhash].js"
                : "[name].bundle.js",
        chunkFilename:
            process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
                ? "[name].[fullhash].js"
                : "[name].bundle.js",
        library: {
            type: "global",
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            process: require.resolve("process/browser"),
            vm: require.resolve("vm-browserify"),
            crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
            stream: require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            util: require.resolve("util/"),
            buffer: require.resolve("buffer/"),
        },
    },
    experiments: {
        topLevelAwait: true,
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        client: {
            overlay: {
                errors: true,
                warnings: false,
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: "process/browser",
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Buffer: ["buffer", "Buffer"],
        }),
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name,
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            exposes: {
                "./app": "./src/spa",
            },
            shared: {
                ...deps,
            },
        }),
    ],
};

if (process.env.STANDALONE_SINGLE_SPA === "true") {
    webpackOptions.optimization = { runtimeChunk: "single" };
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
    //transpileDependencies: ["src/standalone.ts"],
    devServer: {
        port: 9021,
        headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }, // allows hot reloading under parent app
    },
    publicPath: "auto",
    configureWebpack: webpackOptions,
    chainWebpack: (config) => {
        // this is needed for webpack module federation in vue cli until they fix
        // https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6823
        config.optimization.delete("splitChunks");

        // https://vuejs.org/api/compile-time-flags.html
        config.plugin("define").tap((definitions) => {
            Object.assign(definitions[0], {
                __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__: "false",
            });
            return definitions;
        });
    },
});

The content vue.config.js is nearly identical so i have ommitted it.  I have tried adding the el prop in the singeSpaVue() options object.  I have also added hard coded elements in the layout file to mount the apps to.  It doesn't seem to matter where I put it, they always seem to overwrite one another.  I always end up with 2 mounted apps, either 2 content apps, or 2 header apps.  Most often it is the content that double mounts.
I apologize for the lengthy post but I have looked at this for 5 days straight and I am all out of ideas.  I know this is a lot of code but maybe there is something obvious I am missing.  I also realize our application registration process is somewhat unorthodox, maybe that is the issue.  I inherited the parent app and all the code there, I am the author of the vue3 micro frontends.
